# how to fetch data in edit modal sequence/serial vise in laravel using ajax and jquery?

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

i want to fetch data in edit modal and serial vise
when i click on 1 then respected attachment row should be displayed
when i click on 3 then respected attachment row should be displayed

db1 :attachment_master column:attachment_id(primaryid),attachment_title,file_upload_text,is_required
db2: program_fileattachment_mapping column:id,programe_id,attachment_id,status

i want to fetch in edit modal db1. attachment_title, file_upload_text, is_required
db2:status
because i am mapping my attachment id and title
with program id db2

web route:
Route::post('AttachmentMaster','MasterController@addAttachment')->name('addAttachment');
Route::post('addmapping','MasterController@addmapping')->name('addmapping');
Route::get('attachmenthistory',[MasterController::class,'attachmenthistory']);
Route::get('editattachmenthistory/{id}',[MasterController::class,'editattachmenthistory']);

i have tried and in edit function it is showing all data but not row vise
i have tried first() also it only show only one row in every column

my query:
$editAttachment = AttachmentMaster::select('attachment_master.attachment_id', 'attachment_master.attachment_title', 'attachment_master.file_upload_text', 'attachment_master.is_required','program_fileattachment_mapping.status')
->leftJoin('program_fileattachment_mapping', 'attachment_master.attachment_id', '=', 'program_fileattachment_mapping.id')
->where($serialNumber=)
->get();

blade file:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
                                <div class="fade-in">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                                            <div class="card">
                                                <div class="card-body">
                                                    <div class="card-header"><i class="fa fa-align-justify"></i>
                                                        <b>Attachment History</b>
                                                        <div style="text-align: right;">
                                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"
                                                                data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#staticBackdrop">
                                                                Add Attachment
                                                            </button>
                                                        </div>

                                                        <div class="modal fade" id="staticBackdrop"
                                                            data-bs-backdrop="static" data-bs-keyboard="false"
                                                            tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel"
                                                            aria-hidden="true">
                                                            <div class="modal-dialog">
                                                                <div class="modal-content">
                                                                    <div class="modal-header">
                                                                        <h1 class="modal-title fs-5"
                                                                            id="add_attachment_btn">Add Attachment</h1>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                    <form method="post" id="attachment_submit">
                                                                        <input type="hidden" id="id" name="id" />
                                                                        @csrf
                                                                        <div class="modal-body">
                                                                            <div class="form-check">
                                                                                <div class="row mb-3">
                                                                                    <label for="attachment_title"
                                                                                        class="col-4 col-form-label">Attachment
                                                                                        Title</label>
                                                                                    <div class="col-6">
                                                                                        <input type="textbox"
                                                                                            class="form-control"
                                                                                            id="attachment_title"
                                                                                            name="attachment_title">
                                                                                    </div>
                                                                                </div>

                                                                                <div class="row mb-3">
                                                                                    <label for="is_required"
                                                                                        class="col-4 form-check-label"
                                                                                        id="flexCheckDefault">Required</label>
                                                                                    <div class="col-6">
                                                                                        <input type="checkbox" value="1"
                                                                                            id="is_required"
                                                                                            name="is_required">
                                                                                    </div>
                                                                                </div>

                                                                                <div class="row mb-3">
                                                                                    <label for="file_upload_text"
                                                                                        class="col-4 col-form-label">
                                                                                        Size</label>
                                                                                    <div class="col-6">
                                                                                        <input type="textbox"
                                                                                            class="form-control"
                                                                                            id="file_upload_text"
                                                                                            name="file_upload_text">
                                                                                    </div>
                                                                                </div>
                                                                            </div>
                                                                        </div>

                                                                        <div class="modal-footer">
                                                                            <button type="button"
                                                                                class="btn btn-secondary"
                                                                                data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                                                            <button type="submit"
                                                                                class="btn btn-primary"
                                                                                id="addattachment">Submit</button>
                                                                        </div>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                            </form>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>

                                                    <!-- edit modal -->
                                                    <div class="modal fade" id="editModal" data-bs-backdrop="static2"
                                                        data-bs-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1"
                                                        aria-labelledby="editstaticBackdrop" aria-hidden="true"
                                                        data-bs-toggle="modaledit" data-bs-target="#editstaticBackdrop">
                                                        <div class="modal-dialog">
                                                            <div class="modal-content">
                                                                <div class="modal-header">
                                                                    <h1 class="modal-title fs-5"
                                                                        id="edit_attachment_btn">Edit Attachment</h1>
                                                                </div>
                                                                <form method="post" id="attachment_editmodal">
                                                                    @csrf
                                                                    <div class="modal-body">
                                                                        <div class="row mb-3">
                                                                            <label for="attachment_title"
                                                                                class="col-4 col-form-label">Attachment
                                                                                Title</label>
                                                                            <div class="col-6">
                                                                                <input type="textbox"
                                                                                    class="form-control"
                                                                                    id="attachment_title"
                                                                                    name="attachment_title">
                                                                            </div>
                                                                        </div>

                                                                        <div class="row mb-3">
                                                                            <label for="is_required"
                                                                                class="col-4 form-check-label"
                                                                                id="flexCheckDefault">Required</label>
                                                                            <div class="col-6">
                                                                                <input type="checkbox" value="1"
                                                                                    id="is_required" name="is_required">
                                                                            </div>
                                                                        </div>

                                                                        <div class="row mb-3">
                                                                            <label for="file_upload_text"
                                                                                class="col-4 col-form-label">
                                                                                Size</label>
                                                                            <div class="col-6">
                                                                                <input type="textbox"
                                                                                    class="form-control"
                                                                                    id="file_upload_text"
                                                                                    name="file_upload_text">
                                                                            </div>
                                                                        </div>
                                                                        <div class="row mb-3">
                                                                            <label class="col-4 form-check-label"
                                                                                id="flexCheckDefault">Status</label>
                                                                            <div class="col-6">
                                                                                <div
                                                                                    class="form-check form-check-inline">
                                                                                    <input class="form-check-input"
                                                                                        type="radio" name="status"
                                                                                        id="active" value="1">
                                                                                    <label class="form-check-label"
                                                                                        for="active">Active</label>
                                                                                </div>
                                                                                <div
                                                                                    class="form-check form-check-inline">
                                                                                    <input class="form-check-input"
                                                                                        type="radio" name="status"
                                                                                        id="deactive" value="0">
                                                                                    <label class="form-check-label"
                                                                                        for="deactive">Deactive</label>
                                                                                </div>
                                                                            </div>
                                                                        </div>
                                                                    </div>

                                                                    <!-- for ending -->
                                                                    <div class="modal-footer">
                                                                        <button type="submit" id="update_button"
                                                                            name="update_button"
                                                                            class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
                                                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary"
                                                                            data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                                                </form>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="card-body">
                                                <table class="table table-responsive-sm table-bordered"
                                                    id="attachment_tbl" name="attachment_tbl">
                                                    <thead>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <th>Sr No</th>
                                                            <th>Status</th>
                                                            <th>Attachment</th>
                                                            <th>Action</th>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </thead>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td></td>
                                                        <td></td>
                                                        <td></td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </table>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <script>
                        $(document).ready(function(e) {
                            // fetch data
                            function attachmenthistory(programId) {
                                $.ajax({
                                    url: 'attachmenthistory',
                                    type: 'get',
                                    dataType: 'json',
                                    data: {
                                        'programe_id': programId
                                    },
                                    success: function(response) {
                                        if (response.status == 'success') {
                                            $('tbody').html('');
                                            var table = $("#attachmenthistory-table")
                                                .DataTable();
                                            table.clear().draw();
                                            $(response.data.result).each(function(key, value) {
                                                var serialNumber = key + 1;
                                                var isChecked = value.status == 1 ?
                                                    'checked' : '';
                                                var checkboxHtml =
                                                    '<input type="checkbox" name="selected[]" disabled value="' +
                                                    value.attachment_id + '" ' +
                                                    isChecked + '>';

                                                $('tbody').append('<tr>' +
                                                    '<td>' + serialNumber +
                                                    '</td>' +
                                                    '<td>' + checkboxHtml +
                                                    '</td>' +
                                                    '<td>' + value
                                                    .attachment_title + '</td>' +
                                                    '<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary edit-button" data-bs-toggle="modal" id="editbutton" data-bs-target="#editModal" data-id="' +
                                                    value.id +
                                                    '">Edit</button></td>' +
                                                    '</tr>'
                                                );
                                            });
                                        }
                                    },
                                    error: function(response) {
                                        console.log(response);
                                    }
                                });
                            }


                            /*for adding attachment modal*/
                            // $("#addattachment").submit(function(e) {
                            $(document).on('submit', '#addattachment', function(e) {
                                console.log("help");
                                e.preventDefault();
                                let addformData = new FormData(this);
                                $.ajax({
                                    url: 'addAttachment/' + id,
                                    data: addformData,
                                    processData: false,
                                    contentType: false,
                                    type: 'POST',
                                    dataType: 'json',
                                    success: function(response) {
                                        if (response.success) {
                                            swal({
                                                text: response.success,
                                                icon: 'success',
                                                timer: 1000,
                                                buttons: false
                                            });
                                        } else {}
                                    },
                                    error: function(error) {
                                        console.error(error);
                                    }
                                });
                            });

                            $(document).on('submit', '#atchreport', function(e) {
                                e.preventDefault();
                                let addprogramData = new FormData(this);
                                console.log("hi");
                                $.ajax({
                                    type: 'POST',
                                    url: "{{ route('admin.addmapping') }}",
                                    data: addprogramData,
                                    processData: false,
                                    contentType: false,
                                    dataType: 'json',
                                    success: function(response) {
                                        attachmenthistory();
                                        swal({
                                            text: response.success,
                                            type: 'success',
                                            button: false
                                        });

                                    },
                                    error: function(error) {
                                        console.error(error);
                                        swal({
                                            text: 'Program ID Required.',
                                            icon: 'error',
                                            button: false
                                        });
                                    }
                                });
                            });

                            $(document).on('click', '#editbutton', function(e) {
                                // var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
                                // var id = $(this).data('id');
                                var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
                                console.log("edit attachment");
                                $.ajax({
                                    url: 'editattachmenthistory/' + id,
                                    type: 'get',
                                    dataType: 'json',
                                    success: function(response) {
                                        console.log('success');
                                        if (response.status == 'success') {
                                            $('form#edit_customer #id').val(response.data
                                                .id);
                                            $('form#attachment_editmodal #attachment_title')
                                                .val(response.data.attachment_title);
                                            $('form#attachment_editmodal #is_required')
                                                .prop('checked', response.data
                                                    .is_required == 1);
                                            $('form#attachment_editmodal #file_upload_text')
                                                .val(response.data.file_upload_text);

                                            if (response.data.status == 1) {
                                                $('#active').prop('checked', true);
                                            } else {
                                                $('#deactive').prop('checked', true);
                                            }
                                            $('#edit_button').modal('show');
                                        } else {
                                            console.error(response.message);
                                        }
                                    },
                                });
                            });

                            $(document).on('submit', '#attachment_editmodal', function(e) {
                                e.preventDefault();
                                var frmData = new FormData(this);
                                var csrfToken = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
                                $.ajax({
                                    type: 'post',
                                    data: frmData,
                                    contentType: false,
                                    processData: false,
                                    url: 'updateattachmenthistory',
                                    dataType: 'json',
                                    cache: false,
                                    success: function(response) {
                                        if (response.status == 'success') {                                                $('#attachment_editmodal').modal('hide'); console.log("update attachment successfully");
                                            attachmenthistory();
                                            alert(response.message);
                                        } else {
                                            alert(response.message);
                                        }
                                    },
                                    }
                                });
                            });
                        });
                        </script>
```